# Weird "close" link inserted by Gmail "reply" or Firefox "paste"

Tags: firefox, gmail

(Please let me know if there is a more appropriate forum for this; I did my best to research first. At the moment, I don't know if it's a Windows, browser, or Gmail bug.)

*EDIT -- SOLVED: As thkang suggested, disabling add-ons made the problem go away. Stepwise re-enabling identified the "Table of contents" plugin as the culprit. This is a huge relief for me -- thanks for your help. I'll leave the question up in case anyone else is combining Gmail and Table of Contents, but have removed information that turned out to be irrelevant.*

Using the "reply" function in Gmail sometimes inserts the text "Close" at the end of my message, either right away or *after* I press "send". The text is a link with an empty target (unless I use plain text mode, which I generally do). The bug has been with me for months now, but after Gmail's recent switch to a new look and feel for "reply", the "Close" link now sometimes appears as a black rectangle that overlaps the text of my reply.

I always believed this to be a Gmail bug. However, today I saw the same thing when pasting from my plaintext editor (PSPad) into a non-Gmail Firefox tab (some web chat). I pasted "some text" from my editor into the chat edit box, clicked "send" in the chat window, and this is what got posted in the chat:

```
some text

<a target="_blank" >Close <ul />
```

That last line only appeared after I clicked "send", similarly to how the bug manifests after I click "send" in Gmail. However, it never happened again during the chat, when I was typing directly into the chat edit box instead of pasting.

The unclosed "a" tag and empty "ul" might well explain why this messes up formatting in the new pop-out reply box in Gmail. However, I see only a very remote connection between the chat and Gmail, namely that a Gmail background tab was open in Firefox at the same time as the chat. Any help in sorting this out would be greatly appreciated.

This is on 64-bit Windows 7, Firefox 17.0.8 with Table of Contents 1.2.3. (*EDIT: Removed list of extensions that were proven innocent.*)

I would appreciate any help on sorting this out, because it makes me appear confused and/or rude to my contacts... ("Best regards! Close")

Comment: try with firefox in safe mode(no addons).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was caused by the [Table of Contents](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/table-of-contents/) extension for Firefox (version 1.2.3). (The extension's page now says "Not available for Firefox 17.0".) My thanks to the helpful commenter!